# Minecraft 1.14 - Kill two random arrows when shot from a crossbow with multishot enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a command that will kill two **random** arrows shot from a multishot enchanted crossbow (that shoots 3). I wanted to make a bow that would either shoot only left, middle or right. I tried this by adding a scoreboard called 
*CBOW* which detected when a crossbow is shot and ran this command on a repeating command block:

> execute as @a[scores={CBOW=1}] run kill
>   @e[type=minecraft:arrow,limit=2,sort=random]

this does not work for me, so does anyone have any suggestions or fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Just Fixed it. For some reason, the command block that had the commands in it was not working, so I rewrote the command in another command block and it worked!

Comment: This might be caused by [this bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-149038). Nobody knows yet what exactly causes it.